# Record Video With Overlay Image in Ionic

Tags: android, video, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am developing an hybrid app with ionic 3. I require to record video with overlay image on top like snapchat, instagram etc. There's a plugin for it [Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-capture-plus/)

But in documentation it adds overlay only for iOS currently(i want for both iOS and Android) and I don't think it records overlay on top of video. So far i did much research but could not find anything suitable. Any help would be much helpfull thanks

Comment: Hey @Asad35Waheed did you find a solution for this issue? I'm having the same problem and I could really use some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time there are no Ionic 3 plugins available for both iOS & Android with this functionality! Neither has there been any work on the [Video Capture Plus (beta)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-capture-plus/) plugin in over a year!

There is, currently, a beta plugin being worked on called [Camera Preview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/) for both iOS & Android but it only works for images but not videos.